# Indent second line of a bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I am writing a bibliography :

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}
\end{thebibliography}
```

The result :

[image]

And what I would like to obtain :

[image]

I want to indent the second and the third line of `\texttt`. Do I have to redefine `\texttt` or is there an other solution?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

By using the solution of egreg I obtain a strange result :

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Remember that if you have more than 10 bib entries, you have to pu `{99}` in the beginning, instead of `{9}`. The number of 9's ought to correspond to the number of digits of the largest bib label.

Comment: You probably have an outdated version of `enumitem`. What operating system and TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 and MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: If I use enumitem I have problems with the package enumerate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The LaTeX internals can be modified to allow this. We modify:

- `\@biblabel` that prints the label, the new one includes a space of the length `\bibindent`
- `\bibitem` that prints the whole title, to remove the extra space for the first line
- You should add `\kern\bibindent` into the parameter of `\begin{thebibliography}` so that the indentation is ensured
- The line `\def\bibindent` defines the amount of indentation, I set it to `1em`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\bibindent{1em}
\begin{thebibliography}{99\kern\bibindent}
\makeatletter
\let\old@biblabel\@biblabel
\def\@biblabel#1{\old@biblabel{#1}\kern\bibindent}
\let\old@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1{\old@bibitem{#1}\leavevmode\kern-\bibindent}
\makeatother

\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used this to do the opposite - remove indent, thanks. Using `\documentclass[openbib]{memoir}` results in bibliography indents that I didn't want. Adding `\def\bibindent{0em}` before `\begin{document}` fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `enumitem` package to redefine the environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic{enumi}]},itemindent=*,leftmargin=4em]
      \@openbib@code
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit} \texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}

\bibitem{Lorem2}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit} \texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the value for `leftmargin` to suit you. Notice that the argument to `thebibliography` is still necessary, even if it does nothing. This way you won't need to modify the input if you change your mind.

[image]

### **Caveat**

This code is meant for the standard class `article`. For `report` or `book` change `\section` into `\chapter`, while for KoMa-script classes or `memoir` some different hack might be necessary.

Comment: Does it matter if one uses counter enumi (1) or counter enumiv (4)? The latter counter is employed by LaTeX's main document classes in the construction of the bibliography list. Just curious.

Comment: @Mico I guess one can even use `label={[\arabic*]}`, in this case. I didn't want to go too far away from the usual setting. Probably the standard classes choose `enumiv` because it's rarely used in the document.