# How to indent the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indent second line of a bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/indent-second-line-of-a-bibliography)

I need to indent the second line for each paper in my reference list. How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you buiding your bibliography (are you using `BibTeX` or `biblatex`)? Which other relevant packages are you possibly using (natbib)?

Comment: I simply insert the reference into my text by writing         "\bibitem{} Altman, E.I., 1968. Financial ratios, discriminate analysis and the prediction of corporate bankruptcy. {\it The Journal of Finance} {\bf 23}, 589-609"

Comment: Altman, E.I., 1968. Financial ratios, discriminate analysis and the prediction of corporate bankruptcy. The Journal of Finance 23, 589-609---------this is what I get, but I would like to have the second line indented.

Comment: Don't you get any numbering for the references? Can you please edit your question and add a simple complete document illustrating your current actual approach?

Comment: I do have the numbering. And I just found the solution from another post--use the enumitem package

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/indent-second-line-of-a-bibliography－－－this works for me.

Comment: There's no need to use enumitem. I will write a solution without packages; which document class are you using? I I see that the link you provided also has a solution without enumitem, so I won't write my answer.

Comment: I would like to know other solutions. I am using document class-article

Comment: But the other post has also a solution without enumitem, so my answer (although slightly different) would be redundant.

Comment: Thank you very much. This cite is extremely helpful to me!