# Indenting and removing numbers of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I followed the instructions here on how to indent the second line of a bibliography,

[Indent second line of a bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/indent-second-line-of-a-bibliography)

but now I also want to remove the numbers as well. Can someone tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 6):

## Remarks

I used the answer by [tohecz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002/tohecz) in the question you linked: [Indent second line of a bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/indent-second-line-of-a-bibliography).

But beware: With this solution you can no longer reference to bibliography items. **I don't really think, that an unnumbered bibliography is desirable.**

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\def\bibindent{1em}
\begin{thebibliography}{99\kern\bibindent}
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{}
\let\old@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1{\old@bibitem{#1}\leavevmode\kern-\bibindent}
\makeatother

\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}

\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}

\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: This removes the numbers for me but puts all bibliography items in a giant paragraph together with no paragraph breaks. How can I fix that? I am using document style of report, if that matters.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code. I hope it now fits your needs.