# How to indent bibliography items using a bibtex bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting

I have seen an excellent answer for adding an indent to the bibliography here
[Indent second line of a bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/indent-second-line-of-a-bibliography) and wish to replicate that for my example using bibtex rather than putting the bibliography directly into the .tex file like the author of the other question. This is how this question is different.

I was therefore wondering if you could help me adopt the code from that question? I essentially wish to recreate what the other author did adding the indentation for my example, so that I will have the second and third line of each reference indented. For example, the line beginning with 'expectations' would be indented. Thank you very much.

[image: Sample Bibliography]

Here is the code from the other question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\bibindent{1em}
\begin{thebibliography}{99\kern\bibindent}
\makeatletter
\let\old@biblabel\@biblabel
\def\@biblabel#1{\old@biblabel{#1}\kern\bibindent}
\let\old@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1{\old@bibitem{#1}\leavevmode\kern-\bibindent}
\makeatother

\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi.        Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

See for `.tex` file of a MWP below and below that the content of the `bibo.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[aps,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter

\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\newcommand\mycite[1]{% with Numbers 
\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})\@
}
%%%%%Here is the command to be tried out.
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%End of Jerome's custom area
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace{0.6cm}

\title{Test Document}

\author{Me}

%
\date{2 December, 2014}
%

\maketitle

\section{Testing Citations}

As he said, \mycite{ECTA:ECTA438}, we need to be clear on testing. Also, \mycite{RefWorks:14} will play a role. When we now add \mycite{RefWorks:12}.

\section{Introduction}

Hello Intro.

\bibliographystyle{ecta}

\bibliography{bibo}{}

\end{document}
```

WITH BIBLIOGRAPHY FILE:

```
@article{RefWorks:12,
    Abstract = {Abstract.},
    Author = {Sophocles Mavroeidis and Mikkel Plagborg-M{\o}ller and James H. Stock},
    Date-Modified = {2015-01-14 22:54:50 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Economic Literature},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {124-188},
    Title = {Empirical evidence on inflation expectations in the New Keynesian Phillips Curve},
    Volume = {52},
    Year = {2014}
}
@article{RefWorks:14,
    Abstract = {Abstract.},
    Author = {Kang Yong Tan and David Vines},
    Date-Modified = {2015-01-15 13:45:29 +0000},
    Journal = {Available at SSRN 1026339},
    Title = {Woodford goes to Africa},
    Year = {2007}}
@article{ECTA:ECTA438,
    Abstract = {Abstract},
    Author = {Moreira, Marcelo J.},
    Date-Added = {2015-01-14 22:57:58 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-01-14 22:57:58 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1111/1468-0262.00438},
    Issn = {1468-0262},
    Journal = {Econometrica},
    Keywords = {Instruments, similar tests, Wald test, score test, likelihood ratio test, confidence regions, 2SLS estimator, LIML estimator},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {1027--1048},
    Publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd},
    Title = {A Conditional Likelihood Ratio Test for Structural Models},
    Url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/1468-0262.00438},
    Volume = {71},
    Year = {2003}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch `\NAT@thebibliography`and a convenient redefinition of `\@biblabel` (I assume here that you want to suppress the labels for the bib items, as you requested in other question):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace*{\labelwidth}}
\apptocmd{\NAT@thebibliography}{\setlength\itemindent{-25pt}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[aps,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\newcommand\mycite[1]{% with Numbers 
\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})\@
}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace*{\labelwidth}}
\apptocmd{\NAT@thebibliography}{\setlength\itemindent{-25pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Test Document}
\author{Me}
\date{2 December, 2014}
\maketitle

\section{Testing Citations}

As he said, \mycite{ECTA:ECTA438}, we need to be clear on testing. Also, \mycite{RefWorks:14} will play a role. When we now add \mycite{RefWorks:12}.

\section{Introduction}

Hello Intro.

\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{bibo}

\end{document}
```

This is the output (I used the .bib file in your question):

[image]

Comment: That is wonderful. Thank you so much! I will look into these commands some more now. I have seen that when I change the indentation parameter, the text moves left or right with the indented staying in a constant space. Interesting!