# How to make correct References indentation

Tags: bibliographies

I need to use the indentation that you can see in the image...

[image: Reference indentation]

How can I do it? Please give me a help with that code.

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what you have done to try building this bibliography? Can you deliver a minimal working example of your code so far? Further, which bibliography style do you need exactly?

Comment: The question and answers in the example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/indent-second-line-of-a-bibliography may help answer the question proposed.

Comment: With `biblatex author-year` style, this is the default.